# refreshing user.is_authenticated with angular and django rest framework

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework on the backend and angularjs on the frontend. The problem is the login, in angular I do:

```
function ($scope, $http, User) {
        $scope.login = function (user) {
            $http.post('/login/', user)
                .then(function (response, status) {     // success callback
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(response) {     // error callback
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(response);
                })
        }
    }
```

then in my views.py I do:

```
def login_view(request):
    user = authenticate(username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)

    return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

But in my home template which is the only django template that I use, the rest is pure html since I use ui-router with state view, so the {% if user.is_authenticated %} won't get updated and I have to refresh the page manually. Is there any solution to make the 'if' statement in the template to be trigger without refreshing all the page, or any better solution to make a login system in my website?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to add an endpoint to check that and a flag on angular to do that.

Comment: "Is there any solution to make the 'if' statement in the template to be trigger without refreshing all the page?" -- No. Once the page is loaded by your browser, it is just a HTML page. You can't execute any of Django's template logic on the frontend. It's not a bad idea to refresh the page anyway, as the csrf token for any forms will have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use Django's templatescripts in AngularJS.
AngularJS is a SPA. Django's templatescripts does not work well with SPAs.

You need to create your client logic in javascript only. 
This can be done by creating a server endpoint that returns true if a given user is authenticated.